# How to evaluate $ \int_0^\infty {1 \over x^x}dx$ in terms of summation of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

Is there a way to represent this integral in terms of summation of series?
$$ \int_0^\infty {1 \over x^x}dx$$
Like for example:
$$ \int_0^1 {1 \over x^x}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1 \over n^n}$$
I am not getting an answer from [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201/x%5Ex%20from%200%20to%20infinity).

Comment: thanks @Sasha I didn't know that ... but how to evaluate the integral with $ \infty $?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I guess I missed the question.

Comment: your info was helpful ;)

Comment: This doesn't look like an exact duplicate to me.  I vote not to close.

Comment: To start talking about this integral i think you have first to define what is $1/x^x$ when $x=0$.

Comment: it's an improper integral

Comment: thats true. ^_^

Comment: The numerical value is 1.995455957500138000... and the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index) finds nothing.

Answer (score 4):

**A long comment (not an answer)**

Split the integration region, and use the [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream):
$$
   \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x^x} = \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x^x} + \int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x^x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n} + \int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x^x}
$$
Because $x^{-x}$ is strictly decreasing for $x\geqslant 1$, we have
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n} > \int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x^x} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = -1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n} 
$$
Since the $x^{-x}$ is strictly convex function for $x \geqslant 1$, thus
$$
   \int_1^\infty x^{-x} \mathrm{d} x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{1} (n+y)^{-n-y} \mathrm{d} y < \\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{1} \left(n^{-n}(1-y) + (n+1)^{-n-1} y \right) \mathrm{d} y = -\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}
$$ 
We thus established that
$$
    -\frac{1}{2} + 2 \int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm{d} x > \int_0^\infty x^{-x} \mathrm{d}x > -1 + 2 \int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm{d} x 
$$
Numerical confirmation:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the integral from $0$ to (finite) $R$ I get a double sum:

$$\int _{0}^{R}\!{x}^{-x}{dx}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }  \sum _{j=0}^{
k-1}{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{j}{R}^{k} \left( \ln  \left( R
 \right)  \right) ^{j}}{j!\,{k}^{k-j}}}  
$$

The inner sum could be written using an incomplete Gamma function, so:

$$\int_0^R x^{-x}\ dx = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {\Gamma  \left( k,-\ln  \left( R \right) k
 \right) {k}^{-k}}{\Gamma  \left( k \right) }}
$$

I don't see a way to take the limit as $R \to \infty$ on the right, though: each individual term diverges.