# Showing that $\int_0^\infty x^{-x} \mathrm{d}x \leq 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

This integral is very closely related to the sophmores dream that states

$$ \int_0^1 x^{-x}\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n} = 1.27\ldots $$

For example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Now I want to bound the integral, and showing that is less that 2. 
For the interval $[0,1]$ a good bound is rewriting it to $\exp(x\log x)$ and using the expansion

$$ 1 - x \log(x) + \frac12 (-x \log(x))^2$$

but how does one handle $[1,\infty)$ ? In this answer here

[How to evaluate $ \int_0^\infty {1 \over x^x}dx$ in terms of summation of series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184697/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-1-over-xxdx-in-terms-of-summation-of-series)

gives bounds to the integral, but they are not tight enough.. So to taste my question again, how does one prove that

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^x} \leq 2 $$

Comment: Are you sure that it is less than or equal to 2

Comment: According to Mathematica, the value of the integral is $1.99546\dots$

Comment: Hmm.This means that proving that 2 is an upper bound will probably be not easy

Comment: Thank you captain obvious, there is a reason why I asked for help...

Comment: A computation of this integral was carried out by G N Watson, Theorems stated by Ramanujan. VIII: Theorems on divergent series, J London Math Soc 4 (1929) 82-86. It has been carried out to over 100 decimals at oeis.org/A229191.

Comment: Highly accurate approximation way is [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607028/show-that-int-0-inftyx-xdx-pi-ln-pi/4634329#4634329)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since numerically the value is approximately $1.9954559575$, you need very tight bounds.

On $[0,1]$, we can use the "sophomore's dream" series:

$$\int_0^1 x^{-x}\ dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n} \le  \sum_{n=1}^5 n^{-n} + \sum_{n=6}^\infty 6^{-n} = 1+ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{27}+ \frac{1}{256}+ \frac{1}{3125}+\frac{1}{38880} < 1.29129$$

On $[1,\infty)$, the change of variables $u = 1/x$ gives us
$$ \int_1^\infty x^{-x}\ dx = \int_0^1 u^{1/u - 2}\ du $$
Note that since $\dfrac{d}{du} u^{1/u - 2} = u^{1/u - 4} (1 - 2 u - \ln(u))$, 
$u^{1/u - 2}$ is increasing on $[0,1/2]$.  For $0 < u < 1/5$ we have 
$u^{1/u - 2} < (1/5)^{5-2} = 1/125$, so 
$$ \int_0^{1/5} u^{1/u-2}\ du < \frac{1}{625} = .0016$$
On $[1/5, 1]$, we can write 
$$u^{1/u - 2} = \exp(\ln(u)(1/u - 2)) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(u)^n (1/u - 2)^n}{n!}$$
since $|\ln(u)(1/u - 2)| \le 3 \ln 5 \approx 4.828313736$ on this interval, the error in approximating $u^{1/u-2}$ by the first $N$ terms is at most 
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{(3 \ln 5)^n}{n!} \le \frac{(3 \ln5)^{N+1}}{(N+1)!} \left(1 + \frac{3 \ln 5}{N+2} + \frac{(3 \ln 5)^2}{(N+2)^2} + \ldots\right) = \frac{(3 \ln5)^{N+1}}{(N+1)! (1 - 3 \ln(5)/(N+2))}$$
$N=17$ will do, with a bound of approximately $.0004259$.
Thus $$\int_{1/5}^1 u^{1/u-2}\ du \le \frac{4}{5} (.0004259) + \sum_{n=0}^{17} \int_{1/5}^1 \frac{\ln(u)^n (1/u - 2)^n}{n!}\ du$$
Each term has a (rather complicated) closed form.  The result is
$ \int_{1/5}^1 u^{1/u-2}\ du \le .70439$.
Putting all these together, 
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-x}\ dx \le 1.29129 + .0016 + .70439 = 1.99728$$

Comment: Could you please give explicate the bound for  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{17} \int_{1/5}^1 \frac{\ln(u)^n (1/u - 2)^n}{n!}\ du$? Is the bound on each summand coming from a numerical quadrature method?

Comment: As I wrote, each of these terms has a closed form, and I just evaluated them explicitly.

Comment: OK. I see what you are saying.